# Different sized height gap between menu and submenu in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, menu

I have a problem with my Menu. Firefox and IE seem to have different have a different take on how big an em is? I am left with a slight gap for my child elements in Firefox when it looks perfect in Internet Exporer.

I have tried -moz- 'css hacks' in order to change the height dependant on browser but this doesn't seem to work... I'm stuck for ideas.

Firefox (gap)

[image: Gap when viewed in Firefox]

Internet Explorer (no gap)

[image: No gap when viewed in Internet Explorer]

CSS code for changing height differential.

```
.headerextend  {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;
    background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.95em;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
```

The "-moz-sizing" line of code was just something I got off another forum when searching for an answer that didn't seem to do the trick.

The drop down box height can be changed with the "height: 3.95em;" line of CSS. Depending if its set to 3.95 or 4.05 ems will determine which browser it will 'work' in.

Comment: Remove the -moz part altogether cause it's unnecessary and won't work in any browser but Firefox. In any case, you're not showing enough markup to be helped.

Comment: @Rob The line of code does nothing to fix the problem anyway so ignore it. I was using it because apparently IE measures the width of an object from border to border, where Mozilla measures the width in terms of the content so I thought that might have been a solution to the problem.

Comment: the 'border-box' setting allows you have the padding and border inside the element rather than outside. Lets assume you have a 50px element and it has 10px padding and 1px border then the element would normally be 61px height as it summs up. If you set the property it will match 50px height in total.

Comment: @NathTurton I would only use 'em' for content rather than containers. You can just use px (pixels) and it will work.